# Eclipse console doesn't show Tomcat exceptions/stacktrace

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

When I start Tomcat from within Eclipse, I get a console with logging information which are very much what I am used to, they always end with the statement that Tomcat was launched within n milliseconds.

However, whenever an exception occurs, the stack trace for this Exception does not show up in the console. I was used to be able to see them "happen" right from the IDE.

Setting the level in logging.properties to a different value (FINEST or ERROR) brings up the expected changes, but stil no log entry for Exceptions whatsoever.

Does Tomcat log Exceptions in a different way?

The HTTP 500 message mentions the Tomcat logs. So there should be a place where much more info is sent to.

The respective log directories only contain simple access logs and what I see on the console in Eclipse.

Which configuration is responsible for the output to the console?

My logging.properties looks like this:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
org.apache.catalina.level=FINE
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO    
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
```

Comment: You should set the `org.apache.catalina.level` that say `INFO` to `ERROR` and see what happens. From what I know from dealing with logging, that will only as of now log down the the info level and NOT the error level.

Comment: try adding a rolling file appender or similar and look for generated files

Answer (score 1):

Wich logging implementation are you using? in logging.propertie you are configuring apache log. To user pure java log, try to configure programmatically, something like this:

```
        static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(YourClass.class.getName());

        System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format", "%4$s: [%1$tc] %5$s %n");
        //Creating consoleHandler and fileHandler
        consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
        LOGGER.addHandler(consoleHandler);

        //Setting levels to handlers and LOGGER
        consoleHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        consoleHandler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());

        .. When you want to log, do this: 

        LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "HELLO LOG");
```

Comment: This is on the wrong level. I want to get the output that is produced by Tomcat itself, not programmatically log events from my application.